# Indexing and matching rows between two different dataframes using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

first question here so please let me know if I need to elaborate any further.  Essentially, I have two dataframes and I need to index/match (basically vLookUp in Excel) but can't get it working for the life of me.

I have two dataframes.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([['55555', '975 8th Avenue', ""],
                 ['44444', '900 Market St', ""],
                 ['54444', '975 7th Avenue', ""],
                 ['44445', '901 Market St', ""],
                 ['33333', '975 4th Avenue', ""],
                 ['35555', '975 8th Avenue', ""]], columns=['storezipCode', 'streetAddress', 'storeLoc'])
```

and

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([['New York', '53333'],
                 ['New York', '54444'],
                 ['New York', '55555'],
                 ['San Francisco', '44443'],
                 ['San Francisco', '44444'],
                 ['San Francisco', '44445'],
                 ['Chicago', '33333'],
                 ['Chicago', '34444'],
                 ['Chicago', '35555']], columns=['storeLoc', 'storezipCode'])
```

What I'm looking to accomplish is pulling the 'storeLoc' from df_2 and match it against the 'storezipCode' in df_1 and df_2.

In actuality, the two frames of data are nowhere near equal in terms of rows/columns so I think that's been giving me quite the headache.  Does anyone know of an easy solution for this?  In Excel it would be a piece of cake so I feel I'm just overlooking something.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your problem is exactly. Are you trying to find rows in one dataframe that match a certain value for a certain column?

Answer (score 0):

Try `map` and `set_index`:

```
df_1['storeLoc'] = df_1.storezipCode.map(df_2.set_index('storezipCode')['storeLoc'])
print(df_1)
```

Output:

```
  storezipCode   streetAddress       storeLoc
0        55555  975 8th Avenue       New York
1        44444   900 Market St  San Francisco
2        54444  975 7th Avenue       New York
3        44445   901 Market St  San Francisco
4        33333  975 4th Avenue        Chicago
5        35555  975 8th Avenue        Chicago
```